# PDF of Product of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Theta$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. Let $R$ a random variable with probability density $\pi_R(r) = e^{-r}(r^2)/2$. Now define $X = R \cos(\Theta).$ How would one find the pdf of $X$?

Comment: Where is the density of $R$ defined?

Comment: @angryavian Please see the update.

Comment: @openset *Where* is the density defined.  Is the support $[0..\infty)$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, it is defined on $[0, \infty]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the support of $R$ is $\Bbb R^+$. Let $Y=R\sin\Theta$ so the joint distribution of $X,\,Y$ follows from that of $R,\,\Theta$. Since$$f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)=\frac{f_{R,\,\Theta}(r,\,\theta)drd\theta}{dxdy}=\frac{f_{R}(r)f_\Theta(\theta)}{r}=\frac{re^{-r}}{4\pi},$$for $x\ge0$ the PDF of $X$ is$$f_X(x):=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\exp\left(-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)dy\\=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\exp\left(-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)dy\\\stackrel{y=x\sinh t}{=}\frac{x^2}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\cosh^2t\exp\left(-x\cosh t\right)dt\\=\frac{x^2}{4\pi}\int_0^\infty(1+\cosh2t)\exp\left(-x\cosh t\right)dt.$$Since $K_\alpha(z)=\int_0^\infty\cosh\alpha t\exp(-x\cosh t)dt$,$$x\ge0\implies f_X(x)=\frac{x^2}{4\pi}(K_0(x)+K_2(x)).$$In general, the PDF is$$f_X(X)=\frac{x^2}{4\pi}(K_0(|x|)+K_2(|x|)).$$